# Access base class function from derived class

Tags: c++, qt

I just wanted to ask if Im understanding this process right:
http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq17-ratecontrol.html#whoneedstrafficcontrolanyway in this example there is a RcTcpSocket derived from QTcpSocket in which a member function of QTcpSocket is overwritten, namely qint64 RcTcpSocket::bytesAvailable() const.
Does the following line call this member function direclty from the base class:
    QTcpSocket::bytesAvailable()

I mean we are a QTcpSocket but with additional functions and an overwritten function bytesAvailable(). Does this call the non-overwritten function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax forms indeed allows to call an ascendant implementation of a function and not the overridden one.

Most usefull if you want to add code to your own class implementation but still let the parent class do the "core stuff"